# How to give one query result to another query in where condition using codeiginter?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am saving the database using voucher no(the value is automatically incremented) in the tieup_receipt database. In that page, i am using Ac.no also using ajax query the Ac.No details are retrieved when i entered the Ac.no that are stored in tipup_payment database.

Now my problem is during editing I am fetching the data from the tieup_receipt database using voucher no, all the details are fetched but i want to the fetch the acno details also from the tipup_payment database using acno as a input.

i want to give result of one query to another query in where condition.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lztj8.png)

This is an image that are fetching details from the tipup_receipt.
the acno details are emptied such as partyname,loandate,loanamt, due amount.

```
 public function getReceiptEntry(){
  $Code = $this->input->post('Code');
   $this->db->where('TVAcNo', $Code);
    $query = $this->db->get('tipup_receipt');
   // return $query->result_array();
   return $query->row();

}
```

This is a model code for fetching tipup_receipt.

```
    public function getdetails(){

    $TAcNo = $this->input->post('Code');




     $this->db-> select('TRAcNo');
  $this->db-> from('tipup_receipt');
   $this->db->where('TVAcNo', $TAcNo);
    $query =  $this->db->get();

    print_r($query);

$query_result  = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `tipup_payment` where `TAcNo` = `$query`  ");
     return $query_result->row();
}
```

This is model code for the result of one query to another query in where condition.

Comment: Why are u not using joins?

Comment: i don't know how to use Acno from another database in where condition

Comment: try using joins like `$query_result  = $this->db->query("SELECT tipup_payment.*,tipup_receipt.* FROM tipup_receipt LEFT OUTER JOIN tipup_payment ON  tipup_payment.TAcNo = tipup_receipt.TVAcNo WHERE tipup_receipt.TVAcNo = $TAcNo");
return $query_result->row();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try uing inner join.

Assuming the account no. to exist in both tables and voucher no. in tieup_receipt, the query would be:

```
SELECT tr.*,tp.* 
FROM tieup_receipt AS tr 
INNER JOIN tieup_payment AS tp 
ON tr.TAcNo=tp.TAcNo 
WHERE tr.voucher_no=$your_variable.
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Good to know that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

***If you are using CI model functions than you have use this code:***

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tipup_payment');        
    $this->db->where('TAcNo = select TRAcNo from tipup_receipt where TVAcNo = "'.$TAcNo.'"');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
```